# ggplot2 specify a secondary axis for both value and date/datetime

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeserieschart

I am trying to produce a [ggplot](/questions/tagged/ggplot) graph where I can compare two time periods without indexing the data. So, that I get one time-window running along the x-axis at the bottom and one along the x-axis at the top, kinda like the the example from the [tidyverse](/questions/tagged/tidyverse) [manual page](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/sec_axis.html)  (see graph at bottom of linked page).

However I would like to have dual axis on the y-axis too, something like this (made this by copy-pasiting using the code below),
[image: ggplot2 specify a secondary axis for both value and date/datetime]

```
economics_long %>% filter(variable== "pce" & date  > "2008-01-01" & date < "2010-01-01") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, value01, colour = variable)) + geom_line()

economics_long %>% filter(variable== "pce" & date  > "1990-01-01" & date < "1992-01-01") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, value01, colour = variable)) + geom_line()
```

I imagine I would need to use `bind_rows()` to cut the two time periods out and put them on top and maybe make a new variables like `variable` with two options, like `time-window 1` and `time-window 2`, however I wanted to ask here before I start manually build something crazy. Maybe others have done something simular?

I have made some first steps, like,

```
tw01 <- economics_long %>% 
filter(variable== "pce" & date  > "2008-01-01" & date < "2010-01-01")
tw02 <- economics_long %>% 
filter(variable== "pce" & date  > "1990-01-01" & date < "1992-01-01")

tw02$date <- tw01$date
tw <- bind_rows(tw01, tw02, .id = "time_window")
tw %>% ggplot(aes(date, value01, colour = time_window)) + geom_line()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

1. For the date transformation I make use of `lubridate::years`. Addtionally for the transformation inside `sec_axis` I to wrap into `hms::hms` as I otherwise got an error.
2. As I personally find secondary axes always a bit confusing, expecially with both a secondary x and y axis I colored both the x and y labels according to the color of the lines. If you don't like that you can simply drop the `theme()` adjustemnts.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

tw1_START <- "2008-01-01"; tw1_END <- "2010-01-01"
tw2_START <- "1990-01-01"; tw2_END <- "1992-01-01"
s_factor <- .52

Intv <- interval(ymd(tw2_START), ymd(tw1_START))
IntvM <-  time_length(Intv, "month") # time_length(YrDis , "year")


tw01 <- economics_long %>% 
  filter(variable== "pce" & date  > tw1_START  & date < tw1_END )

tw02 <- economics_long %>% 
  filter(variable== "pce" & date  > tw2_START  & date < tw2_END) %>% 
  mutate(date = date +  hms::hms(months(IntvM))) %>% 
  mutate(value01 = value01 + s_factor)


tw <- bind_rows(tw01, tw02, .id = "time_window")
tw %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, value01, colour = time_window)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . -hms::hms(months(IntvM))))  + 
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ . - s_factor), position = "right") +
  theme(axis.text.x.top = element_text(color = scales::hue_pal()(2)[2]),
        axis.text.x.bottom = element_text(color = scales::hue_pal()(2)[1]),
        axis.text.y.right = element_text(color = scales::hue_pal()(2)[1]),
        axis.text.y.left = element_text(color = scales::hue_pal()(2)[2]))
```

[image]